# How to find number of homomorphisms between z8 and s4?

Tags: finite-groups

How to find number of homomorphisms between z8 and s4?
I check by taking image of generator of z8
Say f:z8---->s4
O(f(1))/8
O(f(1))=1,2,4
S4 has 15 elements of order 2 and 6 elements of order 4
15+6+1(trivial)=22
Is this correct?

Comment: I only count 9 elements of order 2: Six with a single 2-cycle and three with two disjoint 2-cycles. Am I missing something? Regardless of which one of us is counting correctly, the rest of the proof looks good to me.

Comment: Arthur, your answer is correct.